# How geolocalisate a new image with a polygon (json file)

Tags: polygon, qgis, pyqgis

l got an sentinel-1 image from Copernicus l downloaded it as TIFF. l did a python code to detect water so now l have a new plot. l would like this plot gets the same coordinate than the image to do so l can use the polygon from the first image to add a localization to my plot.

How can l do it with QGIS or python ?

Thank you